# How do I properly pass values from PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am currently writing a module and I am trying to pass some variables to the `Drupal.settings`.

My module uses the following code.

```
function bcc_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
    drupal_add_js(array('modulname' => array('key' => 'value')), 'setting');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'modulname') .'/script.js');
}
```

The script.js content is the following.

```
(function ($) {
    console.log(Drupal.settings.modulname);
})( jQuery );
```

The output I find in the log is *undefined*, but when I check the content of  `Drupal.settings.modulname` from the browser, it gives me the desired value.

When I add this code, the log shows the right values.

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function({console.log(Drupal.settings.royal)});', 'inline');
```

What is wrong with that? What is the correct code to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first JS snippet executes before the page is done loading.  Is it not the same syntax as the shorthand for declaring the document.onready event handler.

You working example runs from an onready, but the Drupal best practice is to use a behavior, eg:

```
(function ($, Drupal, undefined) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      console.log(settings.mymodule);
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Take a look at [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

okay: this does it:

```
$options = array(
'weight' => 1000, // High number to push this file to the bottom of the list
'scope' => 'footer' // This will output the JS file in the footer scope, so at the end of   the document
);
```

an then hand it over with:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename') .'/script.js', $options);
```

for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330757/drupal-7-add-js-weight

Comment: Alternatively, just wrap the `console.log` call in `document.ready` or `Drupal.behaviors` in your script.js file

Comment: i thought the (function ($) {})( jQuery ); was the document.ready like in Jquery...the drupal.bahavior sounds interesting...thanks for your comment!

Comment: please some critics...not just downvote...

Comment: The downvote is because it is the wrong solution for the problem, and pretty bad advice for future readers.