# Can't pass php variable to javascript in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

Can somebody help me with this problem.
In the body of a Basic page:

```
drupal_add_js(array('my_var' => array('orderid' => '123')), 'setting');
drupal_add_js('sites/all/scripts/printout.js');
```

In printout.js:

```
alert("Before");
alert(Drupal.settings.my_var.orderid);
```

Result:
"Before" was alerted then returned to Basic page, no orderid.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you add the jQuery namespace wrappers in printout.js?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you call for jquery setting inside Drupal behaviour, you can do like this:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.example_name = {
        attach: function(context) {
            alert(Drupal.settings.my_var.orderid);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

or you can call inside jQuery's .ready() event (less preferable than behaviours approach in Drupal world):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   alert(Drupal.settings.my_var.orderid);
});
```

These both approaches ensure that jQuery is loaded before calling a variable.

**P.S.** I recommend using console.log instead of alert for quick debugging, like this:

```
console.log(Drupal.settings.my_var.orderid);
```

Then go to your developer console / firebug (depending on browser you use) and you'll see an output in console.

Comment: Thanks Tim, it works. Didn't realize have to use jquery to get Drupal.settings vars.

Comment: you're welcome :) don't forget to mark this answer as "the answer" :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to say drupal where to put the javascript like this:

```
$options = array(
'weight' => 1000, // High number to push this file to the bottom of the list
'scope' => 'footer' // This will output the JS file in the footer scope, so at the end     of   the document
);

drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'modulename') .'/script.js', $options);
```

But like i learned a more sophisticated way would be to use Drupal.behaviors.

Look at my question: 
[How to pass values from php to javascript properly?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60960/how-to-pass-values-from-php-to-javascript-properly)