# How do I pass a PHP variable to Drupal.settings global javascript?

Tags: 7, javascript

Javascript works fine, but i need to get **my_var** variable from module. At the moment its not working.

Clear my page cache and browser cache several times.

The variable 'my_var' is showing value on front end but not on backend/admin side.

Front end theme is Bartik; the admin theme is Seven.

All other variables are available on Admin side from Drupal.settings, except the one I pass from my custom module.

This works well on both themes.

```
alert(Drupal.settings.basePath);
```

This is my code.

#### MY_MODULE.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_build().
 */
function MY_MODULE_page_build(&$page) {
    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_modal_add_js();

    // HERE it is calling the js
    drupal_add_js(array('MY_MODULE' => array('my_var' => 'MY_VALUE'),), 'setting');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/js/MY_MODULE.js');
}
```

#### MY_MODULE.js

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.MY_MODULE = {
    attach: function(context) {
        alert("test");
        alert(Drupal.settings.MY_MODULE.my_var);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

On front end, it alerts with *test* followed by *MY_VALUE*, but on admin side, it shows *test*; Firebug then shows me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'my_var' of undefined

How can I fix this?

Comment: where are you written drupal_add_js function ?

Comment: @Rupesh In  custom module called MY_MODULE.module

Comment: which function or any hook ?

Comment: in hook_page_build()

Comment: There are nothing wrong in this code. Check may be some typo error.

Comment: Typo can effect all over the site.But it's working fine for front end :(

Comment: As others have said. The code you posted works. Maybe you have a type on the MY_MODULE part of Drupal.settings.MY_MODULE.my_var or the MY_MODULE part of drupal_add_js(array('MY_MODULE' => array('my_var' => 'MY_VALUE'),), 'setting');

Comment: @rooby I'm sorry, I didn't get you. then how is it working for front end.

Comment: Well I use your exact code in a module of my own and it works without the error. The problem is Drupal.settings.MY_MODULE does not exist in your js, so either you have a typo in your js or in your php that adds the js.

Comment: Can you see your custom setting in the HTML source on admin theme? Check the text etc.. matches expected.

Comment: sorry I did post the ans in wrong place ... Thanks for deleting

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this question:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60960/how-to-pass-values-from-php-to-javascript-properly

Answer (score 1):

calling drupal_add_js in hook_init is a fairly standard response to this kind of question, as is hook_boot.

hook_init is used for setting up things required by the page - but doesnt run on cached pages.

hook boot is used for code that has to run on cached pages as well as uncached pages.

The way I usually debug this kind of thing is with the javascript console. In chrome, open the console and type

```
Drupal.settings
```

hit enter and it should print out the whole settings object for you to inspect. This will let you see what you have.

I suspect the problem may be down to when hook_page_build gets fired on admin pages if Im reading your question correctly.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'my_var' of undefined
```

means that

```
Drupal.settings.MY_MODULE
```

evaluates to undefined. It could be at any level. 
so try the javascript console trick and see what you find (is Drupal there.. is drupal.settings there).

you could also try

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.MY_MODULE = {
    attach: function(context,settings) {
    alert("test");
    alert(settings.MY_MODULE.my_var);
   }   
  }
})(jQuery);
```

which is more keeping with how it is documented for [behaviours](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722) on drupal.org

Answer (score -1):

your problem is here

```
    drupal_add_js(array('MY_MODULE' => array('my_var' => 'MY_VALUE'),), 'setting');
```

you should wrote

```
drupal_add_js(array('MY_MODULE' => array('my_var' => 'MY_VALUE')), array('type','setting'));
```

Comment: `drupal_add_js(array('MY_MODULE' => array('my_var' => 'MY_VALUE')), array('type','setting'));` is wrong.