# How do I include a JavaScript file and pass the value of a PHP variable with a single function call?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a PHP variable to my JavaScript file. The file is js/backgroundConfig.js, it's in the theme directory, and this is the content of the file.

```
(function($, Drupal){
  Drupal.behaviors.backgroundAnimation = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      alert(Drupal.settings.variableName);
      alert(Drupal.settings.basePath);
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

`Drupal.settings.basePath` is displayed correctly, but I've no idea how to pass `variableName` from template.php. I've tried a couple of methods but none of them work.

There are tons of examples on the web but none of them contains the filename and the settings together. Like this one:

```
drupal_add_js(array('variableName' => 'value'), 'setting');
```

Alright, but where I should put my filename? I always add my JavaScript file like this.

```
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/backgroundConfig.js');
```

How do I combine it together?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass values from php to javascript properly?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60960/how-to-pass-values-from-php-to-javascript-properly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to combine it togather?

You don't - Javascript files and settings are two completely different things. Anything you add to the settings will be available on the global `Drupal` object, which will be available by the time the code in your JS file is invoked.

Your code should be:

```
drupal_add_js(array('variableName' => 'value'), 'setting');
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/backgroundConfig.js');
```

Or the other way round, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: variables should be specific for Drupal.behaviors.backgroundAnimation

Comment: ??? @HimanshuPathak What does that mean?

Comment: He is calling js like Drupal.behaviors.backgroundAnimation, so we should make variables specific for object backgroundAnimation, see below ex

Comment: Your example is misleading - you're saying that the OP is accessing the wrong variable, when they aren't It's just coming from the global var rather than the local. And variable names are arbitrary, they do not have to be namespaced. What if that behaviour wanted to make use of another global var, perhaps the basePath? With your reasoning, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: oh he is also defining globally :P

Comment: Nope, _Drupal_ defines it globally. Always :)

Comment: So why we add them inside an object? in this case backgroundConfig ? we should call each variable like settings.var1, settings.var2 ? .. :)

Comment: To avoid collisions with other variables of the same name, nothing more

Comment: to be well ordered per module as well

Comment: Nope, it's just a rudimentary namespacing technique for a language that has no such feature.

Comment: Thanks guys for help. This first line explains everything. That's what I was looking for. I was pretty sure that filename and settings should be somehow passed togather to use it, but as Clive explained clear enough that these are completly separate things. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 2):

You are really close.  There's a small error and perhaps a bit of misunderstanding.

First, adding a setting should be (taken from [api.d.o](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)):

```
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')), 'setting');
```

This setting can now be accessed in a .js file via `Drupal.settings.myModule.key`.  The first array key above is the name that you will use to access your settings object in `Drupal.settings`.  This way you can add multiple settings to `Drupal.settings.myModule` if required.

When you're adding js via `drupal_add_js`, there's really two different things that can happen.  If you're adding a *file*, like `backgroundConfig.js`, Drupal will actually load that file into the HTML, allow it to be aggregated, etc.

When adding a setting, there is no file to be added, rather all it does is create that setting as an object within the global `Drupal.settings` JavaScript object that is present on every page.

So, in summary, you can add a file, or add a setting.  Often this setting will be used by a module/theme's behaviour to determine how it is to function on a given page or context.

Also, in your browser, try opening up your Web Inspector, go to the console, and type `Drupal` to get a better idea of what's happening here and how other modules and themes use this feature.

Answer (score 1):

An example would probably be best:

The PHP:

```
drupal_add_js(array('myvar' => 'value'), 'setting');
```

The JS:

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.backgroundAnimation = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      alert(settings.myvar); // Should alert 'value'
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

It's usually good idea to group your settings using the module name like so:

```
drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => array('myvar' => 'value')), 'setting');
```

So to access it via JS you do like so:

```
settings.mymodule.myvar
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot use a single `drupal_add_js()` call to add:

- Two or more internal scripts
- Two or more external scripts
- An external script, an internal script, and a setting

If you need to add one or more of those, you simply call `drupal_add_js()` more than once. The code you shown is perfectly fine.

```
drupal_add_js(array('variableName' => 'value'), 'setting');
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/backgroundConfig.js');
```

Eventually, to avoid conflicts with other themes/modules, and if the value is used only from your theme, you should use the name of your theme/module as array key for the settings.

```
drupal_add_js(array('themename' => array('variableName' => 'value')), 'setting');
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/backgroundConfig.js');
```

Answer (score -3):

Suppose there is some function in template.php

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  drupal_add_js(array('backgroundAnimation' => array('variableSetting' => 'VariableSetting_output', 'variableSetting1' => 'Himanshu')), array('type' => 'setting'));
  drupal_add_js(path_to_theme().'/js/backgroundConfig.js');
}
```

Place the file backgroundConfig.js at proper location.
Then in JS file write like

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.backgroundAnimation = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        alert('js file loaded');
        console.log(settings);
        alert('basePath is ' + settings.basePath);
        alert(settings.backgroundAnimation.variableSetting);
        alert(settings.backgroundAnimation.variableSetting1);
    }
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: This is incorrect - that `settings` var _is_ `Drupal.settings`. `Drupal.settings.variableName` and `settings.variableName` are the same variable.

Comment: my point was to define locally and call locally, globally does not make sense

Comment: You can't _define locally_, all settings go on the global `Drupal` object. Which just so happens to be passed along to all behaviour attachments, so you're incorrectly assuming it's a different var. It isn't